# How do I update a TextView in a different XML file with a button from the MainActivity.class?

Tags: java, android, textview

I want to press the [Create New Follower] button and it increment the **textview** in **followers.xml** by one, each time the button is pressed.

Here's my MainActivity.class

```
package com.couchmango.godslife;

import android.app.*;
import android.content.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.view.View.*;
import android.widget.*;
import java.util.*;
import android.preference.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity       implements OnClickListener
{
    //Declare Constant Variables
    private Button createFollowerButton;
    private int followerLimit;
    private boolean reachedFollowerLimit;
    public static int FollowerCount;
    public static TextView numberOfFollowers;


    //Called when activity opens
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //Create Button
        createFollowerButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.createFollowerButton);
        createFollowerButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        numberOfFollowers = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numberOfFollowers);

        };//End onCreate

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        // Restore UI state from the savedInstanceState.
        // This bundle has also been passed to onCreate.

        }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
        {
        switch(v.getId()){

                //Milestones Button Pressed
                case R.id.milestones:Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, milestones.class);
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                break;

                //God Stats Button Pressed
                case R.id.godStats:intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, godStats.class);
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                break;

                //Influence Button Pressed
                case R.id.influence:intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, influence.class);
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                break;

                //Followers Button Pressed
                case R.id.followers:intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, followers.class);

                MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                break;

                //Create Follower Button Pressed
                case R.id.createFollowerButton: 

                    numberOfFollowers = (TextView) numberOfFollowers;
                    FollowerCount++;

                    if(reachedFollowerLimit == false){AddFollower();}

                    if(followerLimit == 10){

                    reachedFollowerLimit = true;

                    Context context = getApplicationContext();
                    CharSequence toastText = "Follower limit reached";
                    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, toastText, duration);
                    toast.show();

                    }//end if()
                break;
            }//END SWITCH

        }//End OnCLICK





    //Adds Follower
    //everytime button is clicked
    public final void AddFollower()
        {


        followerLimit++;
        FollowerCount++;

        }//End names()


    private class Follower
        {
            int influence;

            public Follower(int influence)
                {
                influence = 1;

                }

        }



    public void startWorshipping()
        {


        }
}//End MainActivity`
```

The issue I'm having is that I want the button to increment a textview by one each time the button on the main activity is pressed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application)

Comment: if `followers.xml` binded to any other activity or fragment ?

Answer (score 0):

Set the text view's width and height as wrap content in xml.
Then for every button click  increase the textview's text size.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the value in the `shared Preferences` on the button click in the MainActivtiy and in the followers screen you can get the value from the shared preference and show it in the textview.

**UPDATE**

in your MainActivity

declare globally

```
public static final String PREFS = "prefs";
public static final String COUNT = "count";
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
int count = 0;
```

Then in your onCreate initialize both

```
sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
```

Then in your button click

```
count++;
editor.putInt(COUNT,count);
editor.commit();
```

then in the activity where you want to show the value

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
```

in onCreate

```
sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(MainActivity.PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
sharedPreferences.getInt(MainActivity.COUNT,0);
```

this get int value will return the number of clicks

Comment: How would I go about doing this?